# Why is it "una", and not "uno", in this sentence when "favor" is masculine?

Tags: género

Why is the feminine “una” used instead of the masculine “un” at the end of the Spanish sentence, “Voy a hacerle un favor a Ben, le debe una”. Is it because this sentence is elliptical and refers to "a thing" and therefore "cosa" which is feminine, or is it because it refers to a "debt of favor" and therefore refers to "deuda" which is feminine? Or something else?

[image: Duolingo screenshot of the sentence]

Comment: Because duolingo made a mistake. It's seeing Ben as a woman or girl.

Comment: "Deber una" is the set Spanish expression for "owe somebody one". The feminine refers to "deuda": Te debo una deuda.

Comment: No sé si ‘deuda’ sería lo más acertado, pero sí ok

Comment: En este contexto, me parece un poco mal dicho. Porque tambien se podría decir aqui. Le debo uno, por lo del favor y sin la expresión idiomática.

Comment: @Lambie de hecho, le debo uno, suena bastante extraño y al menos en mi país no lo he escuchado. Como una frase popular, bastante coloquial en realidad, se acostumbra a decir «te debo una» por la explicación dada por tac

Comment: @matdlara No en el vacío, en *este contexto donde ya viene la palabra **favor***.  Yo sé lo que quiere decir "te debo una".

Comment: Another case where an elliptical "una" is used is the expression: No se pierde una, meaning "he/she never misses out on anything". In this case, we can guess that what is omitted is the noun "ocasión".

Answer (score 4):

**Deberle una a alguien** es una expresión superidiomática que equivale a deberle un favor a alguien. Yo lo pensaría como una elipsis del objeto: ‘le debo una (ayuda)’; pero se dice en forma elíptica, no lo decimos completo.